# How to get index by using Array find() method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to find an index that is a first element satisfied condition by using Array find() method in Javascript. I thought it would return 2 as a result. But the output is 3. Please let me know if my code is wrong.

```
const arr1 = [1, 3, 11, 30, 29];

const result2 = arr1.find((element, index) => {
  element > 10;
  return index;
})
```

Comment: Use [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) instead

Answer (score 3):

You should use Array `findIndex` instead of `find`.

```js
const arr1 = [1, 3, 11, 30, 29];

const result2 = arr1.findIndex(element => element > 10);

console.log(result2);
```

Answer (score 0):

On your code, you are going to find the first index that satisfies the condition.

In that case, you should use `findIndex` instead of `find` as the following code.

```js
const arr1 = [1, 3, 11, 30, 29];

const result2 = arr1.findIndex(element => element > 10);

console.log(result2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Index starts from 0(zero) and hence position of element is index + 1.

```
const arr1 = [1, 3, 11, 30, 29];
```

Considering your example array, 11 is at index 2 of arr1 and if you want your code return absolute position, just add one to index.

```
const result2 = arr1.find((element, index) => {
  if(element > 10) return index + 1;
});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find
See this reference. the find function should return true/false.